# Updating Facebook Page Post published field

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm working on an app that (part of it) will manage the pages of an user and its posts. The user can create a post and choose if the post is published or not. I can create the posts and set perfectly the 'published' field to true of false. The problem is: When I try to set 'is_published' field of a post from false to true via a http POST request. Video a and link type post work perfectly, but status and photo don't work. What may be the problem?

```
    public dynamic PublishPost(string postId)
    {
        dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();

        parameters.is_published = 1;

        try
        {
            return FacebookClient.Post(string.Format("/{0}", postId), parameters);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return null;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Updating unpublished/scheduled posts is possible by using the Post ID that is returned when creating a post. We support two types of updates on such posts:

- Publishing a previously unpublished post. (Unpublishing a post is not
  supported)
- Changing the schedule (i.e. Rescheduling, Adding schedule to an
  unpublished post, Removing schedule from a post thus making it
  unpublished.)

To update an existing post from unpublished to published, simply set the `is_published` parameter to `true` via an API call.

**refer to:** https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#unpub_scheduled_posts

---

The parameter for post is `published`
**Refer to:** *Photo Page Post*
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/unpublished-page-posts/

```
curl -F 'message=Book your trip to Alaska, http://bit.ly/alaska'\
     -F 'source=@alaska.jpg'\
     -F 'published=0'\
     -F 'access_token=PAGE_TOKEN'\
  https://graph.facebook.com/{page_id}/photos
```

---

**Try:**

```
public dynamic PublishPost(string postId)
{
    dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();

    parameters.is_published = "true";

    try
    {
        return FacebookClient.Post(string.Format("/{0}", postId), parameters);

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: I tried. But it throws the exception:
(OAuthException - #100) (#100) Requires one of the params: is_hidden,is_published,scheduled_publish_time,is_pinned,timeline_visibility,backdated_time,message

Comment: According to documents, POST param = published
and GET param to filter = is_published

Comment: When you made your tests, did you use the published to update a post info?